# How to search for a value in array of objects and get it in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How to search an array of objects and get a specific value if exists, and if not, take something else in Laravel 5.8?

```
Collection{
    #items: array:3[
       0 = Object{
         attributes[
         "id" => 1
         "name" => 'google'
         "url" => 'https://google.com/'
         ]
       }
       1 = Object
       2 = Object
    ]
}
```

So out of this how to check if in this array there is an attribute `url` that has `google.com` in it? If something like this does not exists than get something else?

Is it possible to do this without looping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the collection variable is `$sites`, you should be able to use the `->contains()` [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-contains) to check if any of the `$sites` contains the google url:

```
$hasGoogle = $sites->contains(function ($site, $key) {
    return $site->url == 'https://google.com';
});

if ($hasGoogle) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

A `boolean` is returned from the `->contains()` method.

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome. :)